# remove object from the list if certain statement is true

Tags: c#, .net, linq

using linq I want to check certain condition, if that condition is met I want to remove that object from the list

pseudo code

```
if any object inside cars list has Manufacturer.CarFormat != null
delete that object

if (muObj.Cars.Any(x => x.Manufacturer.CarFormat != null))
{
    ?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using the List function RemoveAll, you can

```
muObj.Cars.RemoveAll(x => x.Manufacturer.CarFormat != null);
```

Comment: Technically that's not Linq - just a normal method on `List`.

Comment: yep you're right. edited.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have this `RemoveAll` method on `IList`

That's because `RemoveAll` is a method on `List<T>`, not `IList<T>`.  If you don't want to try casting to `List<T>` (what if it fails?) then one option is loop through by index (in reverse order so as to not mess up the index counting:

```
for (int i = muObj.Cars.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(muObj.Cars[i].Manufacturer.CarFormat != null)
        muObj.Cars.RemoveAt(i);
}
```